# VBA-Compare sheets and copy values from second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two workbooks and copy the 5th column to the 5th column first workbook if the first 3 columns match.

This check has to be done throughout the worksheet.

Worksheet 1:

```
| Heading 1 | Heading2 | Heading 3 | Total | Number1 |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------|---------|
| ABC       | EF       | GH        |       |         |
| XYZ       | AB       | EF        |       |         |
| HIK       | IJ       | PQ        |       |         |
```

Worksheet 2:

```
| Heading 1 | Heading2 | Heading 3 | Total | Number1 |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------|---------|
| QRS       | EF       | GH        |       | 5       |
| XYZ       | AB       | EF        |       | 4       |
| DEF       | QR       | IV        |       | 16      |
| HIK       | IJ       | PQ        |       | 8       |
```

Desired output:

```
| Heading 1 | Heading2 | Heading 3 | Total | Number1 |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------|---------|
| ABC       | EF       | GH        |       |         |
| XYZ       | AB       | EF        |       | 4       |
| HIK       | IJ       | PQ        |       | 8       |
```

I tried to do the following, but it didn't work:

```
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For i = 2 To 100

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i,5).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(AND(Table2[@[Heading1]]=Consolidated!RC[-4],Table2[@[Heading2]]=Consolidated!RC[-3],Table2[@[Heading3]]=Consolidated!RC[-2]),Table2[Number1],"" ""),"" "")"

Next i
```

I am a VBA novice and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I have no idea what output you want, can you make this clearer

Comment: Your data layout is too difficult to read. Appreciating that not everyone will be able to access images, perhaps consider using an  online  [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so as to be able to enter a nicely formatted table for people to view and/or copy.

Comment: I have edited it for you but if anything is wrong, please try and edit this yourself so is legible (after rendering, not just on entry).

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Be specific and see [ask]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the edit.The current code specified copies the 5 th column only if they are in the same row in Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2( ie the value gets copied for XYZ but not for HIK in the above example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with formulas, no need for code. I'll assume that "Heading 1" is in cell A1 for this: Add a new column between heading 3 and Total. In the first cell add the formula =A2&B2&c2 and copy down. Do the same in the other workbook. Now in Number1 in the first book enter this formula

```
  =IFERROR(OFFSET([OtherWorkbook]SheetName!D2,MATCH(D2,[OtherWorkbook]Sheetname!D2:D5),2),"")
```

(Using your workbook and sheet names. Now copy down. You can then hide the column we added at the start by setting its width to zero in both books.